# NPM publish/pack doesn't include content from symlinked directories on Windows

Tags: npm, npm-publish

NPM doesn't follow directory symbolic links, nor directory junctions. Is there some configuration or way to force NPM to include also files from such directories?

Minimal reproducible example. Folder structure:

```
hello/
├── foo/
│   └── foo.js
└── bar/
    ├── package.json
    ├── bar.js
    └── foo/ (SYMLINK)
```

Two types of symlinks doesn't work:

```sh
bar> mklink /J foo ..\foo
```

```sh
bar> mklink /D foo ..\foo
```

The pack command

```sh
bar> npm pack
```

produces the tar package without `foo/foo.js` and no `foo/` folder.

```sh
$ npm -v
# 8.0.0
```